# Why did Sonju help the kids escape?

Tags: the-promised-neverland

In *The Promised Neverland* season 2 episode 3 somewhere around 8:00, Sonju mentioned that he wants to eat natural-born humans, and that's why he is helping those kids.

1. But what I understand from the plot is that demons eat humans to maintain their physics and intelligence, and Senju has both of them. So why does he want to eat those children's natural-born babies?
2. If he really wanted to eat natural-born humans, then why did he help them in episode 11 to escape to the human world? Also, he could have eaten Ratri as he is a human and brilliant.

Did I miss something important from the series?

Comment: is this a spoiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, Sonju doesn't need to eat humans to retain his intelligence and humanoid appearance. But to explain why is somewhat of a spoiler:

> His traveling companion Mujika, is the Evil-Blooded. Rather than explain myself, I'll quote the [wiki](https://yakusokunoneverland.fandom.com/wiki/Mujika#Evil_Blood): "Mujika is a special demon who retains the characteristics and sapience of humans without requiring to consume them. Other demons who ingest a drop of her blood gain the same abilities and are also able to spread this unique body composition to other demons."

Mujika and Sonju both follow a religion that forbids them to eat farm-raised humans. Thus, Sonju thinks it would be okay to hunt humans born in the wild, and this is something he wants to do.

I haven't seen the anime yet, which I think may tell a different story from what I've gleaned, but I've read the manga up to volume seventeen. From what I've seen, Sonju seems quite loyal to Mujika (and for good reason given her ability). Though it may be his private wish to hunt humans again, he might listen to orders from Mujika if it is her wish to help the children escape to the human world. I can't say this definitively though.

For the last point: If I understand correctly, I think the promise makes it forbidden for the demons to attack the Ratri clan, and any humans from the other world. I could be wrong. I'll try to verify this at a later time.

Comment: Note: in anime, degenerated killed Ratri clan pursuers.

Answer (score 0):

Sonju mentions that in the manga, he helps them because of a "promise". It seems that he cannot eat them then. (from what I remember.) I think it's because the humans belong to the other demons from the farms, and he cannot trespass into the human part of the world. I think I remember him wishing for the kids to break the promise so he can eat humans since the farm kids are not available to him. Even if he could eat most of the farmed humans, there are only four high-quality farms. So yeah, basically it's so he can eat humans without the promise getting in the way. I hope this helps :)