# Can the demons harm the Ratri Clan?

Tags: the-promised-neverland

I was trying to answer [Why did Sonju help the kids escape?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/62351/why-did-sonju-help-the-kids-escape), when it occurred to me that I can't actually recall the details of the Promise between the demons and humans and the inner workings of how it works for the demons. I think it's binding on the demons' side, as I recall them saying something like "only the humans can break it". I don't actually own the manga, but this question is probably just a quick look-up for anyone who has access to it.

Could the demons harm or eat Ratri clan members under any circumstances?

Comment: is this a spoiler?